# What contents does acceptedEpoch and currentEpoch contains?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

In zookeeper data directory there are two files called `acceptedEpoch` and `currentEpoch`. Can someone please explain what information these two files contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two files reflect the epoch numbers that the given server process has seen and participated in.